# Override style for RadioButton if it is placed in a Menu

Tags: c#, xaml, styles

is there any way to override the default style of the radiobuttons, if it is placed in a menu? 
but if it is in the window, it should look like ever. but i will not use x:key. it should found this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions:

1. Create style with x:Key but place it in Menu.Resources - that way it will be only applied to menu items.
2. ItemsControls (Menu is one) have property called [ItemContainerStyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector.aspx). You can create Your own [StyleSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.styleselector.aspx) and set style depending on container type.

Comment: to 1. if i have a item, which is noch radiobutton,  it works too? or it crash's? the last is, that i not can use code-behind, because it is a ressource dictionary

i create the style at the menu.resources and then it works for all or i create the style about the menu-style and call it at the menu.resources? how call i it?

Comment: and i can't set resources on a menu style.

Comment: solution 1 works, if i put it on each window... but i will put it only on my resourcedictionary. 
solution2 i had no idea how you meen it - can you give any example?

Comment: Second link is about creating and setting StyleSelector. Inside selectstyle method You can try:

Comment: i had used a controltemplate and put it to the resources of them.
it works fine :>

Comment: and on the second link is only a example, how to call and nit how to use ;)

yet i must only build a controltemplate for menu, which changes only the resources^^

Comment: how had i define a template, which should not change the design of the menu? it should only add the resources. and my only option is the controltemplate, i think.

only

`<ContentPresenter />`

doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy, if you know how :)

```
<style TargetType="{x:Type Menu}"> 
<Setter Property="Template>
<Setter.Value>
 <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Menu}">
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <Style Targettype="{x:Type Radiobutton}>
         </Style>
 </ControlTemplate>
      <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height=  {TemplateBinding Height} />
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</style>
```

you have to control the writing of the keywords, because i write it so and not on Visual Studio.
override the menu standard with a stackpanel, because i had found no other way to set the Resources.
It is easy, but without the answer from Varius, i didn't found this.
You have to do the same for MenuItem.

I post this, because i think, it maybe would help other peoples with the same problem.
i had searched long time and find nothing.